# Cannot retrieve QueryString Value From URl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have pass Url on Anchor tag  Given below:

```
mail.Body += string.Format("<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period={0}&ProductName={1}\">Demo Download</a>", DateTime.Now, productName);
```

And trying to retrieve this value on pageload of download.aspx page  but it  shows `null` value on it. My code is:

```
 string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string;
```

Comment: Just a guess ... `productName` may contain special characters(`=`, `/`, etc)    have you checked what is the result URL your `string.Format(...)`?

Comment: yaa i m puting my result here so You can get more Idea

Comment: Welcome Mr.purvang pandya<br><br>To abc Webnology<br><br>Thank u for putting inquiry for Sms ;<br><br>Please Click on Following Link To Download Your Demo<br><br><a href="http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?period=10/04/2013 6:03:56 PM&ProductName=Sms">Demo Download</a>

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue due to the slash (/) in the formatted date you are passing `10/04/2013 6:03:56`

Format this date to 10-04-2013 6:03:56 by using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh mm")
```

Then you can retrieve query strings by:

```
string PName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"] as string; 
string Period = Request.QueryString["period"] as string;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: still its not working  I think i have to retrive both the value  how  to retrive both the value ?

Comment: Can you paste the URL displayed at the top of browser after clicking the "Demo Download" link?

Answer (score 0):

i think your entire url is not well formed. try escaping values like that...

```
string queryString = string.Format("period={0}&ProductName={1}", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now.ToString()), System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("any product name"));
string body = string.Format("<a href=\"http://www.abc.co.in/Download.aspx?{0}\">Demo Download</a>", (queryString));
```

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some product"))  sir here "Some Product" means?

Comment: It means any string value. You can pass your product name variable (and any other variables used as url parameter) to UrlEncode function. For example; some product names (eg: 24" LCD Monitor/TV) may be incorrect as url parameter. You must encode these variables (24%22%20LCD%20Monitor%2FTV). Try this tool for experiencing url encoding/decoding http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/